# Decorating a class with protected methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to do the exactly the same thing described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742900/java-decorator-pattern-can-i-decorate-a-protected-method), but in C#.

```
public interface IFoo { void DoSomething(); }

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomething() {...}
    protected void Bar() {...}
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public Foo2 (Foo foo) { _foo = foo; }

    public void DoSomething() {...}

    protected void Bar()
    {
        _foo.Bar(); // cannot access Bar() from here
    }
}
```

I looked at several similar questions, but none of them really tell you exactly how to solve this problem. Is trying to decorate a class with protected method a wrong thing to do in the first place?

Comment: The entire idea about `protected` is that it is only accessible in the current class and its subclasses. You will never be able to access it in a class that just holds a reference to it, both in Java and C#.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/614844/682480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protected methods are only visible to subclasses. If `Foo` and `Foo2` are in the same assembly you can make `Foo.Bar` internal instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    internal void Bar() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that `protected` methods can be used in derived classes and `private` methods cannot.  So it's not a matter of right or wrong, but rather it's a matter of whether or not you need that functionality.

[See this SO answer for more clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614844/682480).

Answer (score 0):

You may make intermediate class FooInternal:

```
public interface IFoo { void DoSomething(); }

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomething() {}
    protected void Bar() {}
}

public class FooInternal : Foo
{
    internal void Bar()
    {
        base.Bar();
    }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    private readonly FooInternal _foo;

    public Foo2(FooInternal foo) { _foo = foo; }

    public void DoSomething() {}

    protected void Bar()
    {
        _foo.Bar(); // can access Bar() from here
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are making Bar as a public method there.

Comment: By @Lee advice you may make this method internal. I have updated my answer.